# Interface reference shows weird output

Tags: go

I am trying to understand Go's interface concept and create following code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Failer interface {
    Error() string
}

type Succer interface {
    Success() string
}

type Result interface {
    Failer
    Succer
}

type Fail struct{}

func (*Fail) Error() string {
    return "Error"
}

type Succ struct{}

func (*Succ) Success() string {
    return "Success"
}

type Combi struct{}

func (*Combi) Error() string {
    return "Error"
}

func (*Combi) Success() string {
    return "Success"
}

func main() {

    var r Result
    var s Succer

    c := &Combi{}
    r = c
    s = c
    fmt.Println(r.Error())
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

As output I've got

```
Error 
Error
```

Why? I've expect as output error and success, because `s` it is the interface of type Succer, there is no error return as string.
And when I change the main function like this:

```
func main() {

    var r Result
    var s Succer

    c := &Combi{}
    r = c
    s = c

}
```

the compiler complain

```
# command-line-arguments
.\sample1.go:42: r declared and not used
.\sample1.go:43: s declared and not used
```

Why? I assign variables `r` and `s` a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fmt.Println(s)` prints "Error" because `error` is special-cased in the `fmt` package

```
        switch v := p.arg.(type) {
        case error:
            handled = true
            defer p.catchPanic(p.arg, verb)
            p.printArg(v.Error(), verb, depth)
            return

        case Stringer:
            handled = true
            defer p.catchPanic(p.arg, verb)
            p.printArg(v.String(), verb, depth)
            return
        }
    }
```

The `fmt` package first checks if an object is a `Formatter`, `GoStringer`, `error`, or `Stringer` , in that order, to obtain a value to print.

As for your last question, you have to use a variable, not just assign it. Printing them removes the error.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your first question - if you add `fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(s))` - you'll see that the output is not `Succer` but `*main.Combi`.

Now, since it implements the `Error` interface and has `Error() string`- `Println` thinks it's a go error object and prints the output of its `Error` method.

Changing the `Error` method to anything else will stop `Println(s)` from printing "Error". But it won't print "Success" either.

Answer (score 0):

In your first question, if you want to print success with `s` call a `success` func:

```
fmt.Println(s.Success())
```

About the second question, `Go` compiler check unused variables, so only assign it without use it show compilation error